# Convert Thrift to xsd generator producing php

Tags: xsd, generator, thrift

I'm using the latest version of Thrift and trying to generate XSDs out of my Thrift schema.

When running thrift_0.10.0 --gen xsd mySchema.thrift it generates a php file !?

Why is there no xsd generated but instead a php file ?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Why a PHP is generated or why no XSD is generated? **PHP**: no idea, ask the original autor. **XSD**: see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you add at least one `service` to your IDL the XSD file will appear.